# How to add a dynamic web URL in a button in contact's Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: web, hyperlink, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I need to add a button in each contact record in Dynamics which dynamically generate a link for each contact id, a link (static part( a web URL)+ &select id=contact id from each contact) which is a hyperlink for another website.
Any help. I am new to dynamics

Comment: Can you please explain what dynamic component is mentioned? Is it just contactid?

Comment: We have unique contact id for each contact in contact form. yes it is just contact id

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll post what you might do in the "Answer" section.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [following url](https://d365demystified.com/2020/09/22/pass-execution-context-to-js-script-function-as-a-parameter-from-a-ribbon-button-in-dynamics-365-ribbon-workbench/). For your URL you can compose that URL on the fly like:

```
function openExternalUrl(formContext) {
        var url = "https://yourexternalurl.com?id=" + formContext.data.entity.getId();
        Xrm.Navigation.openUrl(url);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the link for the video.

Comment: Yeah, the video wasn't perfect. Found a better article for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to add a formula field formatted as URL. Simple join of url text and contact id.

[image]

Add this field on form, and it will be clickable via globe button.

[image]